# vim keybindings to use system clipboard mac

Tags: macos, vim, clipboard

Since vim doesn't support native clipboard on OS X by default, I decided to create some keybindings to emulate it.

I started with such a command, which passes visual selection to pbcopy and replaces selection with command output. Since it has no output and just deletes text, i immediately undo the change.

```
:vmap c !pbcopy<CR> :undo<CR>
```

It works fine, but not if I'm copying the last line in the file. It is copied well, but undo doesn't bring it back. If I manually undo later, it works fine.

Is there a way to make this binding work with on the last line as well?

Comment: Mac OS X's default Vim is old and compiled with a feature set too restricted to make it useful beyond editing random files. Instead, grab the latest MacVim and use the bundled CLI Vim which supports the system clipboard.

Comment: It seems I'm going to do so, but not touching clipboard, why undo doesn't work with last line in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between the first `<CR>` and `:undo`:

```
:vmap c !pbcopy<CR>:undo<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with setting a keybinding, but I've never felt the need to.

As with all platforms, Vim **does** save to the system clipboard, but only when using the visual commands.  Select using any of the visual commands (V, shift-V, Control-V).  Then yank.  Whatever was visually selected will be on the system clipboard.

Comment: No, it's not. I've tried it at first. Maybe that's because default vim on Mac OS X is compiled without system clipboard support.